# How to create local for similar variables

Tags: python, function, loops, local, statsmodels

I am trying to run a local and tvp-var for a panel in StatsModel. Time is the index and all variables must be in columns in order to be in line with the state space set up (contrary to the classical panel set up). I have a number of variables that are common and are only differentiated in their names by adding the ISO country code. That is for inflation and GDP in Australia, the USA, and Canada, which would be AUS_inflation, USA_inflation, CAN_inflation, and AUS_gdp. USA_gdp CAN_gdp. There are about one hundred countries and fifty such variables.
What I need is to create a local, a list, a dictionary or whatever that reads and considers them as a single variable when it iterates, e.g., local inflation, local GDP, etc. Ideally, there would be a single value, allowing me to run the local model of StatsModel and obtain results as a panel. How is that done?
I thought that creating a local or what ever could help me solve the problem.
For the local model, I run the following code for the gdp growth rate

```
#2
    # Construct a local level model for Growth rate 
    mod = sm.tsa.UnobservedComponents(dta.gdp, 'llevel')
    
    # Fit the model's parameters (sigma2_varepsilon and sigma2_eta)
    # via maximum likelihood
    res = mod.fit()
    print(res.params)
    
    # Create simulation smoother objects
    sim_kfs = mod.simulation_smoother()              # default method is KFS
    sim_cfa = mod.simulation_smoother(method='cfa')  # can specify CFA method
    fa = mod.simulation_smoother(method='cfa')  # can specify CFA method
    
    #3 
    nsimulations = 20
    simulated_state_kfs = pd.DataFrame(
        np.zeros((mod.nobs, nsimulations)), index=dta.index)
    simulated_state_cfa = pd.DataFrame(
        np.zeros((mod.nobs, nsimulations)), index=dta.index)
    
    for i in range(nsimulations):
        # Apply KFS simulation smoothing
        sim_kfs.simulate()
        # Save the KFS simulated state
        simulated_state_kfs.iloc[:, i] = sim_kfs.simulated_state[0]
    
        # Apply CFA simulation smoothing
        sim_cfa.simulate()
        # Save the CFA simulated state
        simulated_state_cfa.iloc[:, i] = sim_cfa.simulated_state[0]
    
    #4
    # Plot the Growth rate of GDP data along with simulated trends
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(15, 6))
    
    # Plot data and KFS simulations
    dta.gdp.plot(ax=axes[0], color='k')
    axes[0].set_title('Simulations based on KFS approach, MLE parameters')
    simulated_state_kfs.plot(ax=axes[0], color='C0', alpha=0.25, legend=False)
    
    # Plot data and CFA simulations
    dta.gdp.plot(ax=axes[1], color='k')
    axes[1].set_title('Simulations based on CFA approach, MLE parameters')
    simulated_state_cfa.plot(ax=axes[1], color='C0', alpha=0.25, legend=False)
    
    # Add a legend, clean up layout
    handles, labels = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
    axes[0].legend(handles[:2], ['Data', 'Simulated state'])
    fig.tight_layout();
    
    #5 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 3))
    
    # Update the model's parameterization to one that attributes more
    # variation in GDP growth to the observation error and so has less
    # variation in the trend component
    mod.update([4, 0.05])
    
    # Plot simulations
    for i in range(nsimulations):
        sim_kfs.simulate()
        ax.plot(dta.index, sim_kfs.simulated_state[0],
                color='C0', alpha=0.25, label='Simulated state')
    
    # Plot data
    dta.gdp.plot(ax=ax, color='k', label='Data', zorder=-1)
    
    # Add title, legend, clean up layout
    ax.set_title('Simulations with alternative parameterization yielding a smoother trend')
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.legend(handles[-2:], labels[-2:])
    fig.tight_layout();
```

Comment: Some context about what you're trying to do with the value of those variables would be helpful.  A small code sample that shows what you have tried / what you are trying to do, and desired inputs / outputs would also increase the likelihood of someone being able to answer this.  I would recommend reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks.I have edited the post.  In sort, I am trying to run a statespace model in statsmodles  for a panel, and I am looking for the right set up